# 'Bypass' execution on huge resultset

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, asp.net-4.5

We've recently updated the web-based reports in our application to allow users to search for data using wide-ranging search criteria, e.g. *show me all training courses attended, dating back to 1990*.

While customers are happy with this, on occasions (for one very large customer), SQL Server can return huge resultsets, e.g. 900,000 rows.  This can take upward of five minutes to retrieve from SQL and pass to ASP.Net.

While I want to be able to provide flexibility in the report tools, I need to limit the resultsets to be manageable by the user/browser, and minimise the time that SQL is 'locked' into doing this.

The technology stack is as follows:

```
ASP.Net 4.5 web forms <> Data Access Layer <> SQL Procs <> SQL 2012 Standard
```

The logic in the proc's is typically:

1. Perform first SELECT into a table variable (from indexed-tables using required parameters (this is the bit that takes all the time))
2. For each additional parameter, filter the data from the table variable
3. Return all rows, or if the user has requested grouping, return grouped data.  In grouped logic paths (e.g. by site/by country) additional SELECTs are also performed to pull in additional data

Can anyone advise how they would manage this in their own work?  SSRS has been dismissed on cost.  So far I have trialled the following idea, and welcome any feedback:

1. Set a maximum row limit at application level (10,000 rows)
2. In each procedure, set a value of `SELECT TOP (@n)`, `@n` being 10,001 rows.  This stops SQL churning away for five minutes in certain cases
3. ASP.Net checks the resultset row count, and if `> 10,000`, discards the resultset and provides a friendly error message

This works well and forces 10,000 records to be returned in around five seconds or less, regardless of the user's search criteria.  However, although there is probably a better way, the fundamental issues I still have are:

- The user can request grouped results, so may only get 2 rows of data, which has taken five minutes to provide while all 900,000 rows are grouped.  Therefore this DAL check is bypassed
- `TOP (@n)` on the initial SELECT can make the grouped results inaccurate

I was wondering if I should throw an exception instead, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: Try "Set Rowcount" to see if that helps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Comment: MSDN says *"Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in a future release of SQL Server"* so I avoided it.  Anyway, the result is the same as TOP(N).  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SP split two paths or have two SP’s so that the Group By Operation is done during the initial select into your table variable when the Group By option is requested.    You will still have to do a Group By also at the end if you are doing multiple selects into your temp table but this initial select will do the massive grouping ahead of time.     It is on each of these initial selects into your table variable that you should apply the TOP operation on.   You might want to just put 10,000 on all of them for all queries in your current situation.     Big Caveat, You should experiment with putting an ORDER BY on each of your selects that are TOP(n) .  You will notice a performance hit because you  are now making a deterministic query in effect.  You may need this deterministic effect as opposed to a random Top(n) records which will be faster.

 
 In short try to limit at the initial SELECT before you hit the table variable. 

  At an application level I would be totally on board with your discard all if over 10,000 solution if I was driving an interactive app page.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't do grouping initially because additional queries are run to pull in specific additional data into the grouped resultset, which is specific to each grouping options and performed in the respective logic branch (e.g. by person/by site/by country etc).  The problem is that even as I apply Top(N) early, the grouped results get skewed.  Its almost like I need to just abandon the query if 10,001+ rows are returned in the initial query.  I don't think the user would have an issue narrowing their search criteria and running it again

Comment: Instead of Top try "Set Rowcount" which will stop processing records after a certain number. This may have the result of allowing you to group records without skewing results.